# How to copy certain range of files in single command?

Tags: linux

I have a folder which has files range from 20190501 to 20190530,
so i want to copy files range from 20190503 to 20190517 by single command. Is there any such copy command in linux?

I tried `scp -r 201905* /destination`, but this copies everything file range from 20190501 to 20190530, is there other way to copy certain range of files?

Comment: Hi there, [this question has been answered on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/370403/copy-a-range-of-files-in-command-line-zsh-bash).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scp -r 201905{03..17} /destination`

(I'm assuming you are using bash here)

Comment: Great, please accept the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work